# Background image via CSS to <div> distorts child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first question. 
My code is here on [codepen](http://s.codepen.io/awaybackhome/debug/WomzKM#Action).

I've been tinkering with Bootstrap, CSS, and jQuery in this code in an attempt to place a full-width background image behind the last featurette(From Bootstrap demo) item on my page. I'm guessing the problem stems from the bootstrap container class, but I am hoping for a work around.

I've enclosed the featurette with a div tag, applied an ID of "background1" to it, then used CSS in my attempt to set position to absolute and left:0.

This gets me the position I want (except I'd also like the background image to be responsive as in Bootstrap img-responsive), but the childen? tags inherit the opacity and positioning.

I've tried z-index:-1 unsuccessfully. What also seems to be happening is that the low opacity has allowed the footer to creep up into my last featurette item as if opacity also messes with the z-index.

So my questions are:

1. How can I stretch a BG image across the back of the featurette or any other set of grouped items within DIV tags?
2. How can I make this BG image responsive with Bootstrap or apply the img-responsive class through CSS?

Happy New Year! Thanks for reading!

Comment: Use `background-size` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap your content. Use `<div id="background1"></div>` right before the content, and this:

```
#background1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Kiyomizu-dera%2C_Kyoto%2C_November_2016_-01.jpg/800px-Kiyomizu-dera%2C_Kyoto%2C_November_2016_-01.jpg");
}
```

Comment: This pretty much answers my questions. Thanks. I tried closing off the tag like this before but I'd just disappear. I guess it was because I didn't have the background--cover styling? Would you know how to have the BG image stretch from featurette divider to featurette divider? When I play with screen size it'll just blow through the footer.

Comment: It was because the `<div>` had no content and you hadn't specified a height; in that case the div ends up with a height of zero. If you want it to stretch further out, you'll probably have to actively work against bootstrap at some point. Not sure how sensible that is. Maybe use custom CSS for those sections instead.